# Largest odd number Python code simplification

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization

> Write a program that asks the user to input 10 integers, and then prints the largest odd number that was entered. If no odd number was entered, it should print a message to that effect.

I need to do it without using arrays, exceptions, imports, lists, or the *for* loop. Only conditionals and *while* loops can be used. I wrote the code below, but I feel that my algorithm is too lengthy. Can this program be written in a more concise way? The purpose of my question is to see if there would be a more "Pythonic" way to write the same program, whose code I provided below.

```
s = (input('Enter 10 numbers: '))
t = '' # initialize empty "number" string

x = len(s)-1
y = 0 # initialize checked integer
z = 0 # initialize preceding integer
i = 0 # initialize counter

while i <= x:
    print('i=', i)
    while i <= x and s[i] != ' ':
        t = t + s[i] # concatenate "string number"
        i = i+1
    if len(t) > 0: # to not run out of string index
        y = int(t)
    if y%2 != 0: # compare odd numbers
        if y > z:
            z = y
        if y < z and z%2 == 0: # if y is a negative odd integer
            z=y
    if i <= x and s[i] == ' ':
        i=i+1
    t = '' # reset the "number" string

if z == 0:
    print('No odd numbers entered')
else:
    print('The largest odd number entered is', z)
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Low cyclomatic complexity is not necessarily related with code length. If you are trying to reduce the code length by using one-letter variable names, please don't, that makes your code hard to read. Instead of using comments all over the place try to come up with good names.

Comment: @user202729 Please see my edit.

Comment: What about comparison/arithmetic? Loop comprehension? The functions `range`, `filter`, `map`, `list`?

Comment: @user202729 These would not be allowed, as well as the for loop.

Comment: I don't know why your question got four downvotes. The first thing that struck me about it was typing errors right down to code comments *and your current meta-edit*. Note that the answers are older than your additions to the list of language constructs (not) to use.

Comment: @greybeard What kind of typing errors do you mean?

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for pointing those out, I have corrected them now. For some reason only the French autospelling dictionary is available in my Firefox browser. I've installed several English dictionaries, but they still won't appear. Guess I'll need to debug that.
On a different note, I don't believe this question was downvoted for bad spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read_count = 0
largest_odd = None

while read_count < 10:
    user_input = input('Enter any number')

    try:
        user_input = int(input('Enter a number'))
    except ValueError:
        print("user input {} is not a number".format(user_input))
        continue

    if user_input & 1:
        if largest_odd is None:
            largest_odd = user_input
        largest_odd = max(largest_odd, user_input)

    read_count += 1

if largest_odd is None:
    print("No odd numbers found")
else:
    print("Largest odd number found was {}".format(largest_odd))
```

Now let's dissect that a little bit, we declared variables `read_count` and `largest_odd` to track how many numbers we've seen and what the largest odd was.
Note, I specifically chose, to make `largest_odd = None` in the case where we don't see an odd number.

Next, we loop until the user has entered a valid number 10 times.

The `try-catch` logic is overkill for you sake but it helps protect the program from crashing because of bad input from the user. Try opening up a Python shell and running `int('x')`. You'll see why I want to catch a `ValueError` after doing that.

At first, the line `if user_input & 1` might be confusing but it's a very quick way to determine if a number is odd or not. Of course, you could do `user_input % 2 == 1` but all you really need to check is if the first (Least Significant Bit or LSB) is set which we do by using a bitwise `AND` with the number `1`.

Comment: If I enter all even numbers this will not work, you need to change `if user_input is None:` to `if largest_odd is None:`

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering them in all in one line then you can simply `max()` the `split()` with a guard, and catch the exception if nothing passed the guard, e.g.:

```
In []:
msg = 'Enter 10 numbers: '
try:
    print('Max odd number:', max(int(n) for n in input(msg).split() if int(n)%2))
except ValueError:
    print('No odd number entered')

# 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2
Out[]:
No odd number entered

# 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 5 2
Out[]:
Max odd number: 5
```

Same logic broken out in a `for` loop without the exception:

```
m = None
for n in input('Enter 10 numbers: ').split():
    n = int(n)
    if n % 2:
        m = max(m, n) if m else n

if m:
    print('Max odd number:', m)
else:
    print('No odd number entered')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, exceptions are not allowed in that exercise (not covered in the book yet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to Guttag's finger exercise, chapter 2. The below code also works if either one or more entries are entered as blank.

```
def max_odd():
    """Returns largest odd number from given 10 numbers by the use.
    if the input is not valid, the message is displayed to enter valid numbers"""
    x = [input('Enter a value: ') for i in range(10)]
    x = [int(i) for i in x if i]
    if x:
        try:
            x = [i for i in x if i%2 != 0]
            return(max(x))
        except:
            return('All even numbers provided.')
    else:
        return('Please enter a valid input')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your input is a string that consists of the 10 numbers i.e. "3265491232",

```
from sys import maxsize

string = input("Enter 10 numbers consecutively as a string :\n")

if len(string) != 10:
    print("There should be 10 numbers. Please enter input again")

max_odd_number = -maxsize # set it to the maximum negative value
hasOdd = False # to check if input has any odd numbers 

for number in string:
    if int(number) % 2 != 0: # if number in string is an odd number
        hasOdd = True
        if int(number) > max_odd_number: # if current number is greater than the current max odd number previously saved
            max_odd_number = int(number)
if hasOdd:
    print("Max odd number: " + str(max_odd_number))
else:
    print ("No odd number in input string")
```

Comment: FYI: Comments in Python start with `#`.